# iPhone - self.view is nil in initWithNibName subclass, and viewDidLoad not called

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

I have this cascade :

**Somewhere in the app**

```
- (void) go
{
    MyCustomViewController* controller = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] init];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [controller run];
}
```

**in MyCustomViewController**

```
- (id) init
{
    // there is an if statement here in real to choose another XIB if needed
    // but I only display here the code that is called in my tests
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyXIB" bundle:nil];
    if (!self) return nil;

    self.delegate = nil;

    return self;
}

- (void) run
{
    // do things with self.view
}
```

MyCustomViewController inherits GenericWindowController

**in GenericWindowController**

```
/*- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle*)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if (!(self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) return nil;

    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;  // THE APP CRASHES HERE ! self.view is nil

    ...

    return self;
}*/

// METHOD created following first answers : NOT CALLED
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    // and many other things done with self.view
}
```

MyXIB has its File's owner set to MyCustomViewController and the view is connected.
All files are included and checked into the project.

GenericWindowController is designed to make some standard stuff.
MyCustomViewController extends this stuff to work with a custom View, as designed in MyXIB.

Why self.view is nil in GenericWindowController ?
Why `viewDidLoad` is not called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incredible !!! The problem was because of a missing localization for the XIB. Added the localization, and no problem anymore.

Comment: @TylerPfaff:my app was localized, and one of the localisations files, even if not used because of the device configuration, was missing. I just added it back, and no more problem.

Answer (score 2):

`self.view` is only valid after `viewDidLoad` -- in `init...` it is still `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

A view controller should not try to access its view in `initWithNibName:bundle:`.  It should wait until `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thank you, I missed it because of using an old code that was working... Strange. Indeed, viewDidLoad is not called, neither in the super nor the subclass...

Comment: I edited the question. How can I ensure that the view is inited when run is called ? I mean, the code being ran in viewDidLoad (that is supposed to be ran only once) is not called in such a method because it is not called. How may I do this ?

Comment: You need to read [Understanding How Views Are Loaded and Unloaded](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW2).

Comment: Well, I've overridend loadView to be sure it's called, and it's called. But assuming the doc, if loadView is called, then viewDidLoad should be called. But it isn't. Do you see why ?